# Custom view is not rendered when programmatically taking a screenshot

Tags: android, screenshot, android-custom-view, custom-view

I have created a custom view to display the progress of a value i.e days before a holiday. This renders perfectly when it is displayed on the screen but when I try to programmatically take a screenshot of that screen the custom view is no longer rendered.

This is how it looks when displayed on the screen: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xVbE.png

This is how it looks when I take the screenshot: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMSfs.png

To take the screenshot I am converting the screen to a bitmap and then saving it to the phone's cache. I have tried a few methods to convert to a bitmap:

1. ```
   `val view = constraintLayout
   view.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
   view.buildDrawingCache()
   val bitmap = view.drawingCache`
   ```
2. ```
   `val view = constraintLayout
   val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
   val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
   view.draw(canvas)`
   ```
3. ```
   `val view = this.window.decorView
   view.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
   view.buildDrawingCache()
   val bitmap = view.drawingCache
   val frame = Rect()
   this.window.decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame)
   val statusBarHeight = frame.top
   val width = this.windowManager.defaultDisplay.width
   val height = this.windowManager.defaultDisplay.height
   val bitmapScreenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height - statusBarHeight)
   view.destroyDrawingCache()`
   ```

This is how I'm saving the bitmap:

```
val cachePath = File(this.cacheDir, "images")
cachePath.mkdirs() // don't forget to make the directory
val stream = FileOutputStream(cachePath.path + "/image.png") // overwrites this image every time
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
stream.close()
```

I have already looked at this question [mimic screenshot functionality question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811233/what-android-code-mimics-the-screenshot-function-volume-down-and-power-button-s) and if anyone knew the answer to that, that would really help as when I screenshot using the hardware buttons the custom views are rendered correctly.

So my question is why are my custom views not rendered when taking the screenshot and how can I rectify this? 
Thanks in advance!